# Subtract days from today date and compare after

Tags: perl, datetime

Following situation.

I have a file named `2018_12_03_FileName.log`. Now I get the date from the file (`2018_12_03`).

I want to convert the string to a `DateTime` object, which works too.

```
$chars =~s/_//g;
$chars = Time::Piece->strptime("$chars", "%Y%m%d");
$chars = $chars->strftime("%d/%m/%Y");
```

**Output**

```
03/12/2018
```

After that I want to get the date today - 14 days. But here is one of my two problems. I tried many things, but couldn't find any real solution working for me.

```
my $day14 = DateTime->now();
$day14 -= (2 * ONE_WEEK);
```

Error:

> Cannot subtract 1209600 from a DateTime object (DateTime=HASH(0x6f2d84)). Only a DateTime::Duration or DateTime object can  be subtracted from a DateTime object.

Now the second problem is, I want to compare these two dates and look if the file date is in range or not.

```
my $cmp = DateTime->compare($chars, $day14);
```

Error:

> Argument "15/07/2019" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at
>
> A DateTime object can only be compared to another DateTime object (03/12/2018, 15/07/2019).

So how can I subtract 14 days from the today date and how can I compare these two dates after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're slightly muddling up two Date/Time ecosystems that don't work well together.

You can do this using Time::Piece and Time::Seconds.

```
use feature 'say';
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $chars = '2018_12_03';

my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($chars, '%Y_%m_%d');

my $date14 = $tp - (2 * ONE_WEEK);

say $tp->strftime('%d/%m/%Y');
say $date14->strftime('%d/%m/%Y');
```

Output:

```
03/12/2018
19/11/2018
```

Or you can do it using DateTime and friends.

```
use feature 'say';
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => '%Y_%m_%d',
  on_error => 'croak',
);

my $chars = '2018_12_03';

my $dt = $date_parser->parse_datetime($chars);

my $date14 = $dt->clone->subtract( weeks => 2 );

say $dt->strftime('%d/%m/%Y');
say $date14->strftime('%d/%m/%Y');
```

Output:

```
03/12/2018
19/11/2018
```

As for your last question, you can compare either Time::Piece objects or DateTime objects using the standard Perl comparison operators (`<`, `==`, `>=`, etc). But you have to compare two objects of the same type.

Comment: I thought it was something in that direction. Thank you!

Comment: But when I'm using clone it gives me this exception: "Can't call method "clone" on an undefined value at ..."

Comment: @ikegami: Yes. Comparing objects of the same time wouldn't be quite as useful :-)

Comment: @poisn: That means that your call to `parse_datetime()` isn't working. Double-check your input string and the format that you're passing to `DateTime::Format::Strptime->new()`.

Comment: @poisn, Add `on_error => 'croak'` to the list of options passed to `DateTime::Format::Strptime->new` if you want an exception with a possibly useful error message on bad input rather than having it just return `undef`.

Comment: I've added `on_error => 'croak'` to the constructor call.

Answer (score 3):

Just another option, [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment) makes date math really simple:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Moment;

my $chars = Time::Moment->from_object(Time::Piece->strptime("$chars", "%Y%m%d"));
my $day14 = Time::Moment->now_utc->minus_days(14)->at_midnight;
print $day14->strftime('%d/%m/%Y');
```

These objects can be compared with normal operators like with DateTime and Time::Piece. Just keep in mind that, since you only care about the day and not time of day, all math should be done according to the same time zone, of which the easiest is of course UTC.